# Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Tags: php, symfony

At this moment, I use Symfony 3, and I don't have any problem in dev.

When I have put my website in prod, i have this error :

```
Attempted to load class "ZoneRepository" from namespace "AppBundle\Repository".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

Code of the ZoneRepository :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;

/**
 * ZoneRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class ZoneRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getZones()
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('z');

        $qb
            ->select('z')
            ->where('z.active = 1')
            ->orderBy('z.id', 'DESC');

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

[img of my stucture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsbml.png)

I tried :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * ZoneRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class ZoneRepository extends EntityRepository
```

But it not works

Have you an idea ?

Thanks

---

Solution :
You put all repositories files in your Entity fold. Don't forget change the

```
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ZoneRepository")
```

Comment: did you clear the cache for prod env?

Comment: can you show us what the entity file looks like? there could be some referencing issues

Comment: Are you sure you use the same case for the file name ? This appends often when you are using the dev mode on windows and the prod mode on linux.

Comment: Yes you can look the img of structure the name is : "ZoneRepository" in AppBundle/Repository

Comment: I've generated the repository via composer, have you an idea ?

Answer (score 6):

I had this error when my file name and class name is different.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, check that the location of the files have the same path as your namespace

for example:

```
use UtilBundle\Entity\Base\BaseClass;

...

class TipoExpediente extends BaseClass {
```

and mi base class is in: /src/UtilBundle/Entity/Base/BaseClass.php

Answer (score 0):

clear the cache and check, use

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
php app/console cache:clear --env=dev
```

adjust file permission if necessary,dev environment cache is disabled for performance and ease of use, prod environment is optimized for speed

Comment: Already made clear my cache with 

php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug and perms : chmod 777 cache -R chmod 777 logs -R